# Difference between multiprocessing, asyncio, threading and concurrency.futures in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

Being new to using concurrency, I am confused about when to use the different python concurrency libraries. To my understanding, multiprocessing, multithreading and asynchronous programming are part of concurrency, while multiprocessing is part of a subset of concurrency called parallelism.

I searched around on the web about different ways to approach concurrency in python, and I came across the multiprocessing library, concurrenct.futures' ProcessPoolExecutor() and ThreadPoolExecutor(), and asyncio. What confuses me is the difference between these libraries. Especially what the multiprocessing library does, since it has methods like pool.apply_async, does it also do the job of asyncio? If so, why is it called multiprocessing when it is a different method to achieve concurrency from asyncio (multiple processes vs cooperative multitasking)?

Comment: `multiprocessing` uses processes. `threading` uses threads. `asyncio` uses an event loop. Processes are better for CPU-bound tasks and aren't subject to the GIL. Threads and event loops are better for I/O-bound tasks. `concurrent.futures` is an abstraction on top of `multiprocessing` and `threading`. There is no connection between `multiprocessing` and `asyncio`.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Let's go through the major concurrency-related modules provided by the standard library:

- `threading`: interface to OS-level threads. Note that CPU-bound work is mostly serialized by the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock), so don't expect threading to speed up calculations. Use it when you need to invoke blocking APIs in parallel, and when you require precise control over thread creation. Avoid creating too many threads (e.g. thousands), as they are not free. If possible, don't create threads yourself, use `concurrent.futures` instead.
- `multiprocessing`: interface to spawning python processes with an API intentionally mimicking that of `threading`. Processes work in parallel unaffected by the GIL, so you can use multiprocessing to utilize multiple cores and speed up calculations. The disadvantage is that you can't share in-memory data structures without using multiprocessing-specific [tools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).
- `concurrent.futures`: A modern interface to `threading` and `multiprocessing`, which provides convenient thread/process pools it calls executors. The pool's main entry point is the [`submit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit) method which returns a [handle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) that you can test for completion or wait for its result. Getting the result gives you the return value of the submitted function and correctly propagates raised exceptions (if any), which would be tedious to do with `threading`. **concurrent.futures should be the tool of choice when considering thread or process based parallelism.**
- `asyncio`: While the previous options are "async" in the sense that they provide *non-blocking* APIs (this is what methods like [`apply_async`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) refer to), they are still relying on thread/process pools to do their magic, and cannot really do more things in parallel than they have workers in the pool. Asyncio is different: it uses a single thread of execution and async system calls across the board. It has no blocking calls at all, the only blocking part being the [`asyncio.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) entry point. Asyncio code is typically written using coroutines, which use `await` to suspend until something interesting happens. (Suspending is different than blocking in that it allows the event loop thread to continue to other things while you're waiting.) It has many advantages compared to thread-based solutions, such as being able to spawn thousands of cheap "tasks" without bogging down the system, and being able to cancel tasks or easily wait for multiple things at once. **Asyncio should be the tool of choice for servers and for clients connecting to multiple servers.**

When choosing between asyncio and multithreading/multiprocessing, consider the adage that "threading is for working in parallel, and async is for waiting in parallel".

Also note that asyncio can await functions [executed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools) in thread or process pools provided by `concurrent.futures`, so it can serve as glue between all those different models. This is part of the reason why asyncio is often used to build new library infrastructure.

Comment: I've been looking for an answer to exact same question for long and your answer is what I exactly wanted. So thank you very much for taking time to answer this question.