# Python Gil tasks optimization

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, gil

I developed a simple script in Python to do some random work on multiple targets at the same time using **asyncio** and **tasks**. I have a couple of questions regarding concurrency and the optimizations that the Python interpreter has regarding management of tasks, since I'm a little new in concurrent programming.

My main question is, at what point does Python decide to run tasks concurrently? Is this an optimization that the Python interpreter has at this moment? Or should I explicitly write the according to code using **threads** or **futures**?

Any pointers to interesting posts, experience or documentation is highly appreciated.

I'm attaching a couple of code snippets for comparing them:

```
    # A Python3 example that uses tasks for concurrency
 
    import asyncio
    import time
    
    async def factorial(name, number):
        f = 1
        for i in range(2, number + 1):
            #print(f"Task {name}: Compute factorial({i})...")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            f *= i
        #print(f"Task {name}: factorial({number}) = {f}")
    
    async def main():
    
        print(f"started main at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    
        # Schedule three calls *concurrently*:
        await asyncio.gather(
            factorial("A", 2),
            factorial("B", 3),
            factorial("C", 4),
        )
    
        print(f"started main at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    
    asyncio.run(main())
```

```
    # A second example using threads.
    
    import asyncio
    import time
    
    async def factorial(name, number):
        f = 1
        for i in range(2, number + 1):
            #print(f"Task {name}: Compute factorial({i})...")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            f *= i
        #print(f"Task {name}: factorial({number}) = {f}")
    
    async def main():
        print(f"started main at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    
        try: 
            await asyncio.gather(
                asyncio.to_thread(await factorial("A", 2)),
                asyncio.to_thread(await factorial("B", 3)),
                asyncio.to_thread(await factorial("C", 4)),
            )
        except:
            print("Main routine finished.")
    
        print(f"started main at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    
    
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Thank you!

Comment: There are no implications of GIL on asyncio tasks whatsoever, because they are anyway all running within a single thread. And even if you did use threads for tasks like these here, which spend most of the time in `sleep`, you would not notice any problems caused by GIL.

Comment: Honestly, that's mostly dummy functions simulation high consuming tasks (I might have needed to add that in the post). My question is well.. If I'm generating a ton of those tasks dynamically... is there a point where the Python interpreter will choose to treat those tasks as threads?

Answer (score 2):

> at what point does Python decide to run tasks concurrently?

I think there's some terminology confusion.

I suspect what you mean is:

> at what point does Python decide to run tasks *in separate threads?*

Never. Python won't implicitly run an `asyncio` task as a separate thread.

`asyncio` code is typically written assuming single-threadedness. Implicitly running that code in worker threads would break things.

If you want to do a bunch of work in separate threads or processes, use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` or `ProcessPoolExecutor` from [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures).

If you want to do a bunch of work in a separate threads or processes, *and you also happen to be inside a coroutine,* use something like [`asyncio.loop.run_in_executor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor).

Answer (score 1):

First, you should be aware that asyncio is single-threaded and is designed for parallelizing IO-bound tasks, not for CPU-bound ones. If you need parallelism of CPU-bound tasks, you should use threads or, better, processes.

Second, your second example is simply incorrect - if you use threads, `factorial` should be an ordinary function, not an async one. Your `gather()` expression is equivalent to:

```
result1 = await factorial("A", 2)
result2 = await factorial("B", 3)
result3 = await factorial("C", 4)
await asyncio.gather(
    asyncio.to_thread(result1),
    asyncio.to_thread(result2),
    asyncio.to_thread(result3),
)
```

Rewritten like that, it is obviously wrong. The code is awaiting factorials in sequence rather than in parallel, as intended, and also because it's calling `to_thread` with the return values of `factorial`, which are None because `factorial` doesn't return anything. `to_thread` accepts a *function* (and optionally arguments), so the correct way to define it would be something like:

```
def factorial(name, number):  # note: def, not async def
    f = 1
    for i in range(2, number + 1):
        time.sleep(1)  # note: time.sleep(), not asyncio.sleep()
        f *= i

# ...

# note: don't call `factorial` here, just pass it to `to_thread`
await asyncio.gather(
    asyncio.to_thread(factorial, "A", 2)),
    asyncio.to_thread(factorial, "B", 3)),
    asyncio.to_thread(factorial, "C", 4)),
)
```

You would have noticed a "NoneType is not callable" exception if you hadn't suppressed all exceptions using `try: ... excpet: ...`, which is an anti-pattern.

> Or should I explicitly write the according to code using threads or futures?

Yes, you should use the `concurrent.futures` module to write your code. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61360215/1600898) for a recap of the differences between the various libraries.

Comment: Hi there !! Thank you very much for the very in depth response you wrote earlier. So mabye.. Asyncio is better suited for tasks such as writing to files for example, and concurrent.futures y more for multiple processes running at the same time with differnet goals, or better said, non-blocking operations?

Comment: @DiegoCanizales Yes, asyncio is best suited for IO-bound tasks that have to do with communication: networking, database access, etc. (Writing files is problematic because there is no portable async interface to that.) `concurrent.futures`, especially with a process pool, is better suited for CPU-intensive tasks that need to be sped up using multiple cores. `asyncio.to_thread` allows you to integrate blocking (non-async) code into asyncio using threads for compatibility.