# How to parallelize a For Loop using Python Multiprocessor

Tags: python, loops, parallel-processing

how can I parallelize the following Python function?

I need to transform this simple for loop into a parallelized function using multiprocessor or anything similar.

```
def post_query():

questions_ids = ['1', '4', '5', '6']
for x in questions_ids:

    url = global_url + "card/" + str(x) + "/query"

    payload = json.dumps({
      "ignore_cache": False
    })
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Cookie': 'metabase.SESSION=' + session
    }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

    print(response.text)
```

I Have tried doing multithreading as follows but I don't see that it is being executed in parallel jobs:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    questions_ids = get_cards()
    for x in questions_ids:
        executor.submit(post_query(x))
```

Comment: What did you tried? Multiprocessing is not a good idea here, but multithreading is. Did you read the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool) and the many previous posts about this (including the one specifically referring to requests)?

Comment: I have tried using multithread in the following way:

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
 questions_ids = get_cards()
 for x in questions_ids:
  executor.submit(post_query(x))

Comment: Please read the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61351844/4865723 There are important differences between Threads and Processes in the context of python.

Comment: Could you make sure that the indentation of your code is correct?

Comment: inside for loop ```currentThread = Threading.thread(...) ; currentThread.start()```